# How to work with a shapefile (shp) with folium?

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I am trying to integrate a shp file that I created on Qgis with a map that I created with Folium.

My shp file (gdf) shows railroads and looks like this:

```
    id  EF  geometry
0   None    RS105   LINESTRING (179594.484 -3547126.500, 157006.06...
1   None    RS103   LINESTRING (-235587.484 -3365437.750, -298682....
2   None    RS101   LINESTRING (-30771.531 -3357265.750, -79628.46...
3   None    RS106   LINESTRING (206456.641 -3299645.250, 219854.21...
4   None    RS102   LINESTRING (267157.688 -3326829.750, 269737.11...
```

I am trying to see these railroads on a folium map with the following code:

```
map = folium.Map(location=[-14.235004, -51.92528],
                      zoom_start=4)


folium.GeoJson(data=gdf["geometry"]).add_to(map)
```

It does not work, though. I get the following error:

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)
```

At first, I thought the problem had been generated by the way I installed Geopandas (with Anacondas), but I am not so certain anymore.

Comment: I think the error occurs because the coordinate system of the map is different from the format folium can handle. Try the following code. `import pyproj;gdf.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), inplace=True):m=folium(...);folium.PolyLine(gdf['geometry'],...)`

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand what was your suggestion. Could please give it as a code? Cheers.

Comment: This is an installation issue. Try reinstalling `pyproj` package and check their documentation for troubleshooting.